# Convert <li> text into a clickable link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a scenario where (I won't bore you with the details) I need to convert the text of a series of li's into clickable links (all going to the same destination URL). For instance:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
<li class="link">Australia</li>
<li class="link">Fiji</li>
<li class="link">Oman</li>
<li class="link">Venezuela</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like for the countries to be converted into clickable links.

Using:

```
$( ".link" ).each(function() {
    $( this ).css( "color", "red" );
});
```

I can loop through the li's (although ideally I'd like to be able to 'target' the UL and then it's children removing the need for the class="link"...but that's another matter!) and in this instance simply change the colour of the text but I don't know how to change the text into a link.

Any chance someone could give me some pointers please?

Thanks,
craig

Comment: What is it you want each item to link to? You'll need soemthing there?

Comment: why don't you just wrap your text with an <a> tag? that way you will only need to deal with css ...

Comment: there's a set of circumstances when I just want the text to stay as text but when a logged in user hits the page I want to convert the text in <a> (they all go to the same place)

Comment: As a side note, you can call `.css` without the `.each`. It'll still apply it to every element.

Comment: i'm thinking that i need to loop through them to format each one one ie. keep the country name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```js
$( ".list-inline li" ).each(function() {
    $( this ).css( "color", "red" ).html('<a href="#'+$(this).text()+'">'+$(this).text()+'</a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-inline">
<li class="link">Australia</li>
<li class="link">Fiji</li>
<li class="link">Oman</li>
<li class="link">Venezuela</li>
</ul>
```

But maybe you do not want real links, but just clickable `<li>`s?

```js
$('.list-inline').on('click', 'li', function(event) {
  alert("Go to link");
})
.find('li').css({cursor:'pointer'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li class="link">Australia</li>
  <li class="link">Fiji</li>
  <li class="link">Oman</li>
  <li class="link">Venezuela</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [**html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to write the inner anchor elements without `each()` using a callback

```js
$('.link').html(function() {
  return '<a href="url">' + $(this).text() + '</a>';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li class="link">Australia</li>
  <li class="link">Fiji</li>
  <li class="link">Oman</li>
  <li class="link">Venezuela</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use click since you are using jquery

```
$( ".link" ).click(function(){
 //do something here
alert('clicked');
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: they wouldn't visibly be a link though would they?

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function of `.html()` method:

```
$( ".link" ).html(function(i , oldhtml) {
  return "<a href='someref"+oldhtml+"'>"+oldhtml+"</a>"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'wrapInner' function to do this:

```
$("ul.list-inline li").wrapInner(function() {
    return "<a href='somepage.html'></a>";
});
```

Although if you have access to the source to change the classes, not sure why you don't just code the links in place...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>Australia</li>
    <li>Fiji</li>
    <li>Oman</li>
    <li>Venezuela</li>
</ul>

$( ".list-inline li" ).each(function() {
    $( this ).css( "color", "red" );
    var country = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<a href="yourlink">'+country+'</a>');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6cjex8b2/